# Finding the issue of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase

Tags: exception, tomcat, catalina

I'm trying to use OpenID authorization code, but when it comes to

```
WebAuthentication.login()
```

The exception is thrown

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/valves/ValveBase
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.login.WebAuthentication.login(WebAuthentication.java:78)
    at dotastack.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:61)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I've added the catalina.jar to WEB-INF\lib, to classpath, to Server Classpath, but none of these methods did not solve the exception. Help me guys, what am i doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake was adding `catalina.jar` to `WEB-INF/lib`. You should not set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

If you write a Valve, the Valve itself needs to be in Tomcat's `lib/` directory. You can't deploy a Valve along with your web application.